# How to override session for rails_admin engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I am using Mongoid.override_session() to direct users to their respective databases in a multi tenant architecture.  I have a master db with user login credentials then each customer has their own database with all their data.

I am also using rails_admin but when the Mongoid session gets overridden to the customer database, the rails_admin interfaces are still looking for data in the master.  Is there a way to override the session for rails_admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out and incase it will help someone else, here is what I did.

As it turns out, the rail_admin engine was connected to the correct customer database but was unable to authorize users properly since the user data is in the master.  I ended up replicating the user and roles collections to each customer db and the rails_admin interface works.  Of course this is not ideal since user records have to replicated around but it's an acceptable workaround for now.